# How can I get HTTPD to serve the html/php files and not list/index them when they are in folder for virtual host. Using Centos 6.0

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, centos

My virtual hosts are configured as below, initally I could not even get to the `/public_html/` directory when typing example.com and apache would just serve me up
the default welcome page, I would also get the error: `Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/` in the log . After editing the welcome.conf page (- Index) so it does not show
again when I now type example.com the`/public_html/` contents (Index.php) are indexed in the browser. Where as I want it to actually execute and diplay the index.php page.

vhost.conf , located in etc/httpd/vhost.d/

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

    <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
         ServerName localhost
         ServerAlias localhost.example.com
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/
         ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log
         CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
         ServerName example.org
         ServerAlias www.example.org
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.org/public_html/
         ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.org/logs/error.log
         CustomLog /var/www/html/example.org/logs/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

httpd.conf, settings on default, added onto end:

```
Include /etc/httpd/vhosts.d/*.conf
```

Root directories:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `DirectoryIndex index.php` inside your VirtualHost paragraph(s).

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason PHP file is not interpreted/executed now. Where as before without virtual hosts it worked. Any idea? Thanks..

Comment: @LaserBeak 1) This is a second question 2) It has already been answered 100 times on this page. There is a search box in the upper right corner.